# Issue with understanding a function that counts the longest fence "|------|-|"

Tags: arrays, c, counting

I have an activity:

[image: Problem description]

Let's consider the following test case:

```
|------|-|
      ^^^^ 4
```

it should return 4 i think, but instead it returns 2.

Incorrect attempt: (Caller at the bottom)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 10

//Prototypes: 
int longestFence(char input[], int size);

int main (void)
{
    char fenceString[] = "|------|-|"; // size is 10
    
    printf("%s → %d", fenceString, longestFence(fenceString, 10));
}

int longestFence (char input[], int size)
{
    int longestFence = 1; //Assume the lowest length (similar to Max activity)
    int count = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < size;) //Start comparing from second index
    {
        if (input[i] + input[i - 1] == 169)  //Compare each index with the previous index
        {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        
        else 
        {
            if (count > longestFence)
                longestFence = count;
            
            count = 1; //reset counting
            i++;
        }
    }

    return longestFence; // It should return 4 not 2
}
```

I modified the function by adding the condition that's inside of else to the outside of else too, and now it works as expected and returns 4, but how? I can't understand the logic behind this modification...

Working attempt:

```c
int longestFence (char input[], int size)
{
    int longestFence = 1; //Assume the lowest length (similar to Max activity)
    int count = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < size;) //Start comparing from second index
    {
        if (input[i] + input[i - 1] == 169)  //Compare each index with the previous index
        {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        
        else 
        {
            if (count > longestFence) //repeat this condition outside of else
                longestFence = count;
            
            count = 1; //reset counting
            i++;
        }

        //FIX :
        //The condition is repeated, now it's solved!
        if (count > longestFence)
            longestFence = count;
    }

    return longestFence; // It returns 4 as it should.
}
```

Comment: In essence, they're looking for the longest chain of alternating `|` and `-` characters. So `-` and `|` by themselves count as 1, `|-` and `-|` count as 2 while `--` and `||` count as 1. Your assertion it should return 4 is correct, so that leaves a problem in your code. Your problem lies in `count > longestCount` resetting the count - that should only happen when you hit an invalid continuation of your previous fence. Otherwise, you've reset the count (when it hits 3) before you continued counting the rest of the valid 4-length fence.

Comment: Thanks everyone ..
I added the codes in online compiler

Comment: Please post your code, as text, directly in the question as a [mre].

Comment: `int longestFence = 1;` is also wrong. The longest fence could be zero.

Comment: @ikegami not really ideal to edit the answer into the question, though I closed as not reproducible / unuseful to future readers, so moot point I suppose. I can cast a reopen if you think that's untrue. I think the `'-' + '|'` check overall is pretty ad-hoc: it'd start allowing non-fence characters in the count if it wasn't preconditioned. A part of learning, though.

Comment: @Rogue, Re "*not really ideal to edit the answer into the question*", I didn't. I simply copied the OP's offsite code into the question

Comment: @Rogue The question isn't *how* to fix it, but *why* the fix works.

Comment: Aha, gotcha. I missed that bit looking it over. Re-reading myself now.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
The problem lies in the check place as ikegami mentioned, so I will start looking more from this :)
Also, I'll try to make the code clearer next time.. Still a newbie in this field

Comment: Thx a lot!!
@ikegami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, you should draw out the state of the variables over time on paper or somewhere.

In the broken code, you only update `longestFence` when you find the end of a fence, but you don't consider reaching the end of the string to be reaching the end of a fence. This means that you never set `longestFence` for fences that are found at the end of the string.

The reason the second snippet works is not that you check twice; it's that you check in a different location. (If you get rid of the first check, it will still work.) By checking every loop pass, you ensure the check is performed at the end of the string.

---

Note that your code has a second bug: It returns `1` for an empty string.

---

How I'd write it:

```c
size_t longestFence( const char *s ) {
   size_t max = 0;
   size_t len = 0;
   char prev = 0;
   for ( ; *s; ++s ) {
      if ( *s != prev ) {
         prev = *s;
         ++len;
         if ( max < len )
            max = len;
      } else {
         len = 1;
      }
   }

   return max;
}
```